# C# Storing dynamic data with nested lists

Tags: c#, xml, excel, list

I'm trying to figure out the best method of storing dynamic data from an XML file into a C# list with a sublist. Each XML document will have 1 or many "Sheet" nodes which will always have attributes for "name" and "data". Each "Sheet" element may have 0 to X number of child "Parameter" nodes which will always have attributes for "ParamName" and "ParamValue".

The example data set looks like this:

```
<Root>
    <Sheet name="name1" data="This is data for sheet 1">
        <Parameters ParamName="PraramName1" ParamValue="ParamValueS1.1">
        <Parameters ParamName="PraramName2" ParamValue="ParamValueS1.2">
    </Sheet>
    <Sheet name="name2" data="This is data for sheet 2">
    </Sheet>
    <Sheet name="name3" data="This is data for sheet 3">
        <Parameters ParamName="PraramName1" ParamValue="ParamValueS3.1">
        <Parameters ParamName="PraramName2" ParamValue="ParamValueS3.2">
        <Parameters ParamName="PraramName3" ParamValue="ParamValueS3.3">
    </Sheet>
</Root>
```

I am trying to figure out the best method of storing this data into a C# list for each "Sheet" element with an optional sublist for each "Parameters" element.

```
public class SheetData
{
    public string SheetName { get; set;}
    public string SheetData { get; set;}
}

public class ParameterData
{
    public string ParamName { get; set;}
     public string ParamValue {get; set;}
}

public class ComboData
{
    public SheetData sDat = new SheetData();
    public List<ParameterData> pDat = new List<ParameterData>();
}
```

I'm not sure if I setup the ComboData class correctly or if my issue is with instantiating the class and adding data to it. I've tried a lot of different scenarios to use this class but haven't been able to get it to work. Examples below.

```
List<SheetData> sInfo = new List<SheetData>();
List<ParameterData> pP = new List<ParameterData>();

// This works for the SheetInfo class and also worked when I added a
// reference to a ParameterData list in this class.     
sInfo.Add(new SheetInfo
{
    SheetName = "SheetName",
    SheetQuery = "TheQuery",
});


SheetInfo sIF = new SheetData();
sIF.SheetName = "SName";
sIF.SheetQuery = "SDat";


// This is my most recent failure at adding sheet data with child param data
List<ComboInfo> CombInf = new List<ComboInfo>();
CombInf.Add(new parameters { ParamName = "hth", ParamValue = "dfsf" }, new      SheetInfo { SheetName = "dsdfsd", SheetQuery = "sdfsfs" });


 foreach (SheetData si in sInfo)
 {
     Console.WriteLine(si.SheetName);
 }
```

Perhaps I'm approaching this requirement all wrong and shouldn't be trying to use a list or maybe I'm not instantiating the list and sublist correctly. Any pointers would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about combine the classes:

```
    public class Sheet
    {
        public string SheetName { get; set; }
        public string SheetData { get; set; }

        public List<ParameterData> ParameterData = new List<ParameterData>();
    }

    public class ParameterData
    {
        public string ParamName { get; set; }
        public string ParamValue { get; set; }
    }
```

And add just like your xml is formatted:

```
    sheets.Add(new Sheet()
    {
        SheetName = "Sheet 1",
        SheetData = "FJE35N3LN20",
        ParameterData = new List<ParameterData>()
        {
            new ParameterData()
            {
                ParamName = "Parameter One",
                ParamValue = "1"
            },

            new ParameterData()
            {
                ParamName = "Parameter Two",
                ParamValue = "2"
            }
        }
    });
```

Of course this is all hard coded you'll need to use loops when traversing and saving your xml file.

Comment: Awesome this is exactly what I was looking for. The quick answer is much appreciated. I started out with the combine classes but it looks like I was just instantiating the sub ParameterData lists incorrectly. Thanks for the help.

Comment: @LT-Bienabee im glad you could find it helpful and just let me know if you need any other related help.